# local::reference passing along a reference to local

Tags: java, java-8

I have a Constructor that looks like something as follows:

```
public SqlReader(Schema schema) {
  super(schema::readRow,schema::initialize);
}
```

The main part of the code could look like something as follows:

```
Schema schema = new schema(schemaDefinition);
SqlReader sqlSource = new SqlReader(schema);
schema.groupBy(sqlSource,Column.column("market"),Column.sum("sales"));
result = schema.execute();
```

This is a fictional piece of code to allow me to explain that we are dealing here with lazy execution, where `schema.groupBy` will modify the schema, and `SqlReader` depends on the original schema.

The problem here is that using `schema::readRow`, you pass along the actual reference to `schema` to the member reference and not a copy of it, as this translates to an Anonymous Inner Class where you pass along `schema`.

How can this efficiently improved?

a first attempt might look as follows:

```
public SqlReader(Schema schema) {
  super(schema.clone()::readRow,schema.clone()::initialize);
}
```

Overhead is obvious: now I have created twice a clone. So I might come up with this solution, instead of in the API (SqlReader), I do it in the custom coded part:

```
SqlReader sqlSource = new SqlReader(schema.clone());
```

Issue here is that now I require the user of the API to be aware of this issue, which might be too complex of a topic for the user to understand or remember.

So I come up with a new approach: using a factory, builder, or static creator:

```
public static create(Schema schema) {
  Schema schemaCopy = schema.clone();
  return new SqlReader(schemaCopy::readRow,schemaCopy::initialize);
}
```

It seems that this is such a common issue for parallelized streams, Lambda, and method references, that there must be a more elegant way to address this?

Comment: Exposing only static creator methods is often a good thing, so I would definitely go with your last solution, except I would give the method a more standard name, something like 'of()` or `wrap()` depending on what the parameter means.

Comment: I'm not sure why you see this as a common issue.  In most cases, passing along the actual reference is the normal, perfectly correct and unsurprising behavior.

Comment: You *can* use `super((schema=schema.clone())::readRow, schema::initialize);` in your constructor to create only one clone just as in the factory method. Still, the idea of creating method references to a mutable instance which shouldn’t be mutable doesn’t look convincing. Further, it seems like you are mixing functional programming with object oriented programming. If the base class of `SqlReader` is intented to be subclassed, it should offer overridable methods rather than relying on functions passed in the constructor. In contrast, if it’s not intended to be subclassed, you shouldn’t do it…

Comment: @Holger, in a multi-node system (cluster), Function Object Instances can be streamed to another node for processing to pass along a 'method of doing' vs an 'Instance of doing'. Example, you cannot pass along an instance of a life connection to another node. So this is where I end-up in mixing functional and oo, besides, it is also not me but part of an existing API I am extending (spark). Either way, most of what you state seems very valid, but it will take a while trying to process all that.

Comment: @biziclop this is the method I will be using, although that Holger gave me a way of doing exactly the same way in one shot in the constructor.

Comment: I don't see how this is any different than using an anonymous class.  Unless you clone the object somewhere, you still only have one object.